# React JS passing prop to be mapped

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I am trying to turn my mega-class into smaller reusable components, however, I am stuck on passing prop names to be mapped. The first code-block is my mega-class, I am trying to break it into smaller components shown in my second code block, but an error is give when I try to use props.categoryName.map in the second code block. How else should I approach this?

```
// Sort todos by due date. Completed todos get moved to completed list.
    let today = todos.filter(todo => todo.date === "today" && !todo.complete)
    let completedTodos = todos.filter(todo => todo.complete)

    return (
        <div className="td-app">
            <TodoForm onSubmit={this.addTodo}/>

            {/* <Category categoryName="today"/> */}

            <div className="td-section">
                <div className="td-category">
                    <h2 className="today">Today</h2>
                    
                    <p className="td-count">{todayTodos.length} todos</p>
                </div>
                <div className="td-list">
                        {todayTodos.map(todo => (
                                <Todo 
                                    key={todo.id} 
                                    toggleComplete={() => this.toggleComplete(todo.id)} 
                                    onDelete={() => this.handleDeleteTodo(todo.id)}
                                    todo={todo}
                                />
                        ))}
                </div>
            </div>
```

My component class is here:

```
import React from 'react'
import Todo from './Todo'

const Category = (props) => (
    <div className="td-section">
        <div className="td-category">
            <h2 className={props.categoryName}>{props.categoryName}</h2>
            
            <p className="td-count">{props.categoryName.length} todos</p>
        </div>
        <div className="td-list">
                {props.categoryName.map(todo => (
                        <Todo 
                            key={todo.id} 
                            toggleComplete={() => this.toggleComplete(todo.id)} 
                            onDelete={() => this.handleDeleteTodo(todo.id)}
                            todo={todo}
                        />
                ))}
        </div>
    </div>
)
export default Category
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: It looks like `categoryName` is a string (`categoryName="today"`). A string cannot be mapped, only arrays.

Comment: Thats correct map is used for arrays. []

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You passed `categoryName` as the string literal `"today"`. As that obviously is not an array of `todos` you can't call `.map()` on it. If you also want to map over your todos inside of your `Category` component you also have to pass the todos. Note that you actually have to pass the list as the prop not a string with the name of the variable that holds it:

```
<Category 
    categoryName="today" 
    todos={today} 
    onComplete={this.toggleComplete} 
    onDelete={this.handleDeleteTodo}
/>
```

and `.map()` over it in your component:

```
const Category = ({categoryName, todos, onComplete, onDelete}) => (
    <div className="td-section">
        <div className="td-category">
            <h2 className={categoryName}>{categoryName}</h2>
            
            <p className="td-count">{todos.length} todos</p>
        </div>
        <div className="td-list">
                {todos.map(todo => (
                    <Todo 
                        key={todo.id} 
                        toggleComplete={() => onComplete(todo.id)} 
                        onDelete={() => onDelete(todo.id)}
                        todo={todo}
                    />
                ))}
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my original problem.
However, I am getting: this.toggleComplete(todo.id), the toggleComplete is now undefined. How can I fix this here? toggleComplete is a method in my mega-class.
Do I also pass these in as props? Or is there a more elegant method?

Comment: @Brian You can also pass callback functions as props. See my updated answer.